# Split array in chunks after n elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I want to split an array in `n` parts where each part gets printed on a new line.
Let's say I have the following array which I need in chunks of five:

```
var res = ["dog","bird","cat","bear","cow","fish","ape","worm","ant","fly"];
```

Then the desired result should be:

```
dog,bird,cat,bear,cow
fish,ape,worm,ant,fly
```

When I run this code I only seem to get the *last* chunk printed.

```
<p id="demo"></p>   
<script>  
    var res = ["dog","bird","cat","bear","cow","fish","ape","worm","ant","fly"];
    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 5;    
    for (i=0,j=res.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = res.slice(i,i+chunk) + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temparray;
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must concatenate to get the existing innerHtml already

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temparray;
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a `+` to your `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temparray;`.

```js
var res = ["dog","bird","cat","bear","cow","fish","ape","worm","ant","fly"];
var i,temparray,chunk = 5;

for (i=0; i < res.length; i+=chunk)
{
  temparray = res.slice(i,i+chunk) + "<br>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temparray;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to only write to `innerHTML` just once, instead of updating it once per row of output (which would force the browser to update the display after every row). The for-loop in the following snippet just appends each row to the `temparray` variable, and `innerHTML` is updated just once -- after the for-loop.

```js
var res = ["dog","bird","cat","bear","cow","fish","ape","worm","ant","fly"];
var i,temparray = "", chunk = 5;

for (i=0; i < res.length; i+=chunk) {
  temparray += res.slice(i,i+chunk) + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temparray;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Destructive while loop approach

```js
var res = ["dog", "bird", "cat", "bear", "cow", "fish", "ape", "worm", "ant", "fly"];
var chunks = [],chunk = 4;
while (res.length) {
  chunks.push(res.splice(0, chunk).join(', '))
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chunks.join('<br>');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let idx = 0;
let count = 0;
let tempList = [];
let resultList = [];
let splitSize = 2

while (idx <= array.length)
{
    tempList.push(array[idx++]);
    count++;
    if (count == splitSize)
    {
        resultList.push(tempList);
        tempList = [];
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (!tempList.length)
{
    resultList.push(tempList);
}
```